# C++ accessing member of subclass of abstract class pointer vector

Tags: c++, class, vector, polymorphism, abstract

Error over here:

```
Rocket.cpp:31:16: error: no member named 'getThrust' in 'RocketPart'
    rocket[0]->getThrust();
```

When I want to access `getThrust()` from class `Engine` over the `vector<RocketPart*> rocket` with `rocket[i]->getThrust()`, I get the error message from the top of my question.
What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to access it over rocket[index]->getThrust()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you receive is correct: there is no function called `getThrust` in the class `RocketPart`. You can either:

- add a `virtual float getThrust()` to your `RocketPart` class. This may not be a good solution, because not all `RocketPart` could contain thrust; however, you could simply `return 0` from it, or make it a pure virtual function (which would mean you are no longer to ever create a `RocketPart` object
- `dynamic_cast` your `RocketPart` object into an `Engine`. This can be done with the following:

  `for (size_t r = 0; r < rocket.size(); ++r)
  {
      if (const Engine* engine = dynamic_cast<Engine*>(rocket[r]))
      {
          // able to successfully convert this RocketPart into an Engine
          engine.getThrust();
      }
  }`

You will not be able to cast any `RocketPart*` that isn't an `Engine`

Comment: Can I easily add Engine* engine with the method rocket.addPart() ? Or do I have to cast it back to RocketPart* ?

Comment: Yes you can! Because `Engine` is a derived class of `RocketPart`, any function that takes a `RocketPart` can have an `Engine` passed in instead. This means you can also `push_back` an `Engine` into a `std::vector<RocketPart*>` as well

Comment: Thank you and everyone else here for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

The class `RocketPart` does not have a function `getThrust()` inside of it, which is why your vector calling the function doesn't work. If `getThrust()` is a common routine that will be used in the classes inheriting from it, you should add it as a virtual function in the base class like so:

```
class RocketPart {
public:
    RocketPart();
    RocketPart(const RocketPart& orig);
    virtual ~RocketPart();

    virtual float getThrust();

    virtual void print() = 0;
protected:
    // some members
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
virtual float getThrust() = 0;
```

In your `RocketPart` class.
Besides, I can see absolutely no reason to use virtual inheritance (this is only needed if you inherit from multiple classes **and** you have [The Diamond Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)), so instead:

```
class Engine : virtual public RocketPart {
```

you should be ok with just :

```
class Engine : public RocketPart {
```

I would also suggest looking at your memory allocation(s) - *if your sample source code is not just an example* (you are leaking `Engine` objects, maybe `vector<shared_ptr<Engine>>` would be a better idea ?)

Answer (score 0):

it is because the type stored in the container is RocketPart.
You need to downcast the pointer to Engine.
So instead of

```
rocket[0]->getThrust();
```

you need to write:

```
Engine *pPart = (Engine *) rocket[i]; //you can use also static_cast<> or dynamic_cast<>
pPart->getThrust();
```

Be careful when using cast: if rocket[i] is not an Engine, the program will likely crash.

Answer (score 0):

The method getThrust() is defined in the Engine class not in the RocketPart.
You need to move the method in the base class RocketPart, for access it over the vector.
Alternatively you can also use a dynamic cast for "convert" the RocketPart to the Engine.

```
Engine* engine = dynamic_cast<Engine>(rocket[index]);
if (engine) {
    engine->getThrust();
}
```

Consider that the use of dynamic_cast often means bad design.